# Como dizer "creepy guy" em português?

Tags: tradução-inglês

A palavra *creepy* é frequentemente aplicada a homens que demonstram atração sexual por uma mulher de modo socialmente não-calibrado, como em

*The guy just kept staring at her since we got into the train. Creepy!*

*Touchy-feely guys are creepy.*

Como traduzir essa palavra para o português, quando aplicada a tais homens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Creepy*, nos exemplos dados, [significa](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/creepy) que causa uma sensação como a de coisas rastejando sobre sua pele, ou seja, desconfortável de maneira assustadora, irritante ou repulsiva.

Algumas [traduções](https://www.linguee.com/english-portuguese/search?source=auto&query=creepy) possíveis:

- arrepiante
- assustador, aterrorizante, medonho, sinistro, horripilante
- estranho, esquisito, bizarro, grotesco, surreal

Outro [dicionário](http://www.wordreference.com/enpt/creepy) sugere também:

- repulsivo, repugnante, nojento, asqueroso

Qual o mais adequado vai depender do contexto, tom de voz, etc.

Traduções possíveis para as frases da pergunta:

- *The guy just kept staring at her since we got into the train. Creepy!*
  O cara ficou a encarando desde que chegamos ao trem. Bizarro!
- *Touchy-feely guys are creepy.*
  Caras que ficam tocando/se esfregando na gente são nojentos.

Comment: Acho que sua definição e traduções não capturam a essência psicológica da noção de _creepiness_: a **ambiguidade**. Eu argumentaria como os autores [deste artigo](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.newideapsych.2016.03.003) (negrito meu):

Comment: "But what exactly is it that our creepiness detector is warning us about? It cannot just be a clear warning of physical or social harm. A mugger who points a gun in your face and demands money is certainly threatening and terrifying. Yet, most people would probably not use the word 'creepy' to describe this situation. It is our belief that creepiness is anxiety aroused by the ambiguity of whether there is something to fear or not and/or by the ambiguity of the precise nature of the threat (e.g., sexual, physical violence, contamination, etc) that might be present. Such uncertainty..."

Comment: "... results in a paralysis as to how one should respond. In the mugging situation, there is no ambiguity about the presence or nature of threat. It may be that it is only when we are confronted with uncertainty about threat that we get 'creeped out,' which could be adaptive if it facilitates our ability to maintain vigilance during periods of uncertainty. Thus, it is our contention that **'creepy' is a qualitatively different characteristic than related concepts such as 'terrifying' or 'disgusting' in which the conclusions drawn about the person in question are much more clear-cut.**"

Comment: @DetachedLaconian Talvez "arrepiante" tenha um pouco mais da ambiguidade que você busca. Adicionei outras sugestões de tradução na resposta e troquei "assustador" na tradução da sua 1a frase por "bizarro" - se pode ter uma palavra ainda menos 'clear-cut' com "estranho".

Comment: Estava com medo que fôssemos nos esbarrar com uma limitação da língua portuguesa em si. Fiquei feliz com sua resposta rápida e bem elaborada. Dei uma organizada geral nela e estou esperando passar pelo *review*, mas já a aprovei. Obrigado!

Comment: @DetachedLaconian Legal. Também achei que ficou melhor organizado - aceitei tua edição com modificações mínimas.

Answer (score 0):

*Creepy* pode significar, neste contexto, "estranho" ou "nojento".

Na frase, *Touchy-feely guys are creepy* pode significar:

- Caras que se esfregam ou "se pegam"(além da conta, a ponto de deixar as pessoas desconfortáveis) são nojentos/estranhos.

Comment: Olá. Não sei se foi a intenção, mas "se pegam" soa reflexivo, enquanto *touchy-feely guys* se refere a caras que tocam demais terceiros, não uns aos outros.

Comment: Tem razão. Se refere à caras que pegam demais outras pessoas

Answer (score 0):

O título de uma música da banda Los Hermanos, "Cara Estranho", traduz bem essa expressão considerando "*guy*" como "*cara*" e "*creepy*" como "*estranho*":

- "*creepy guy*"
- "*cara estranho*"

Não que a canção se refira ao caso explicado no enunciado, mas também não creio que haja alternativa perfeita para essa expressão no idioma, então, o título da música parece se encaixar bem como tradução no português do Brasil pelo menos.

E, como [João Pimentel Ferreira observou](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/5192/como-dizer-creepy-guy-em-portugu%c3%aas/5196?noredirect=1#comment13588_5196), em português de Portugal, considerando "tipo" como tradução para "*guy*", teríamos ainda:

- "tipo estranho"

Comment: Podes explicar melhor o porquê da musica definir a questão?

Comment: @gmauch, editei a resposta. Veja se satisfaz suas dúvidas..

Comment: _cara_ em PT-pt seria _tipo_, neste caso _tipo estranho_

Comment: Agradeço pela observação, @JoãoPimentelFerreira! Inclui a sua sugestão para melhorar a minha resposta.

Answer (score 0):

de arrepiar:

**É de arrepiar, é de arrepiar
Esse batidão faz até defunto se levantar**

**É de arrepiar, é de arrepiar
Esse batidão faz até defundo se levantar**

Creepy guy: Esse cara é de arrepiar

Quando o adjetivo é mais do lado literário/rato, o de + verbo funciona bem.

That's creepy: Isso é de arrepiar.

[música](https://www.ouvirmusica.com.br/carlos-viana/e-de-arrepiar/)